# A simple script displays wrong color

Tags: html, display

365 days as ul list.  To Dec 6th colors follow. After 6th, the 7th dissappears and subsequent dates' colors vary.  HTML: gtfont color="Red”lt  17th gt/fontlt  TEXT  for that date.... END HTML
The list created in excel; fixed text - the HTML - filled in by excel. Text pasted  to Notepad, saved, reloaded - copied and used in Homesite

Have not tried CSS to achieve same result (which will probably work) but doesn't answer problem..

Comment: Uhm... What is the problem? What are you trying to do?

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please refer to [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Have you tried to do any research? What have you tried? Questions here should have a clear problem/question, with research shown, and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.